# Track usage by language in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

My blog is a multi language blog, I want to track the number of visits per language. As in x number of people visited language 1 posts while y number visited language 2.

Any idea on how to do this with Google Analytics?

Comment: Do you use the language in the URL as a subdomain, directory, or URL parameter?

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the 'Audience Tab' and click 'Geo' then 'Language' you should see the number of sessions users are viewing your site in that particular language. (See Screenshot)

[image: Google Analytics Menu Bar]

This is based on the language setting on your users' browser when they visit your site.

Following this, you can add a secondary dimension to view which pages/landing pages the user is viewing.